# Undefined error when i try to put a disabled="disabled"

Tags: php, html

I have a select option and put `disabled="disabled"` so that it cannot be selected, but when I try to press the update button it always give me this error.

> error  Notice: Undefined index: Province in
>   D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on line 35

But when i try to remove the `disabled="disabled"` it update successfully. But, i want that disabled to be put there so it cannot be selected..

**The code**

```
$Province = isset($_GET['fruit']) ? $_GET['fruit'] : '';

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $fruit = $_POST['fruit'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="Province" class="form-control" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
       <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $fruut; ?>" disabled="disabled"><?php echo $fruit; ?></option>
       <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
       <option value="raspberry">raspberry</option>
       <option value="blueberry">blueberry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: have you tried just putting `disabled` instead?

Comment: @kim oliveros.. no..

Comment: @Trojan, try the answer below

Comment: @claudios Ok.I'll try it

Comment: I see try it then.. and also I wouldn't suggest you to use inline js

Comment: None of the code you are showing is using `Province` as an index.

Comment: @kim but how shoud i do it?

Comment: @chris what do you mean?

Comment: just add an ID/Class then call that element on your `<script></script>` and do the `onclick `event there anyway your a Filipino aren't you (this might be off topic)?

Comment: An index is the access point of an array, e.g. `$_GET['test']`, here  we are accessing the `test` index of the `$_GET` array. In your code `fruit`, `update`, and `id` are indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will always throws an error because the disabled option is always selected base on your code. To get the fix, remove the selected attribute.

Remove: `selected="selected"`

Now it will look like this

```
<select name="Province" class="form-control" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
       <option value="<?php echo $Province; ?>" disabled="disabled"><?php echo $Province; ?></option>
       <option value="ALBAY">Albay</option>
       <option value="CAMARINES NORTE">Camarines Norte</option>
       <option value="CAMARINES SUR I">blu</option>
</select>
```

Or use this piece of code if you want to select the disabled value as default.

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled" <?php echo $Province; ?>><?php echo $Province; ?></option>
```

Comment: i have try your code and it works but the problem now is that its not showing the current record..like for example..the current record is disabled and if i updated it it is successfull but it shows me the next on the which is ALBAY.

Comment: do you want the disabled option to be the default selected value? is that what you mean?

Comment: It always select what you have selected of course. disabled value will not be selected that's why it's disabled.

Comment: yes..i want the disabled to be my default value

Comment: @Trojan, check my updated answer

Comment: Glad could help :) you may also vote it up :)

Comment: i have try your code for several times, it works on the first 10 tries but after that the problem still occur..what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You have `selected="selected"` in your code. Remove that and it should work just fine.